# Why is it useful to inherit from EventArgs?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I don't understand why inheriting from `EventArgs` is useful.

```
public class ClickedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    int x;
    int y;
    public ClickedEventArgs (int x, int y)
    { 
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y; 
    }
    public int X { get { return x; } } 
    public int Y { get { return y; } } 
}
```

In the code above, how can I use this inheritance?

I also want to learn how I can call this code block from `default.aspx`

Comment: I can't find an example necessarily for this for a ASP.NET scenario.  It's quite common though in Windows Form / WPF if you want to get the exact location of a click.  In web application this type of event is usually handled client side through JavaScript.  I guess it is possible to create a custom control that will pass along these info from JavaScript in a PostBack.

Answer (score 17):

Are you asking why it's useful to derive from `EventArgs` in the first place? I have to say that with C# 1 it didn't make a lot of sense, because of the way delegate conversion worked - but as of C# 2 it's more sensible. It allows an event handler to be registered with an event even if it doesn't care about the details of the event arguments.

For example:

```
void LogEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Event sent from " + sender);
}

...

textArea.KeyPress += LogEvent;
```

This works even though `Control.KeyPress` is an event of type `KeyPressEventHandler`. C# and .NET don't mind that the signature of `LogEvent` doesn't *exactly* match the signature of `KeyPressEventHandler` - it's compatible enough.

Admittedly this would still be feasible if we didn't have `EventArgs` at all (you could just use `object`) but given the `EventArgs` class and the pattern, it makes sense to derive your own event arguments from `EventArgs`.

Comment: There is one very mild advantage to EventArgs over simply using object.  The delegate having the signature (object, object) is more prone to a being called errorenously due to typos in the code.  With a signature of (object, EventArgs) such a typo is much more likely to be spotted at compile time.

Comment: Oh and EventArgs<TEventArgs> has where TEventArgs : EventArgs so if you want to use this Generic instead declaring your own handler type you need to derive from EventArgs.

Comment: Microsoft removed this `where TEventArgs : EventArgs` generic constraint post-.NET 4 ([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/eventhandler.cs)). Inheriting from EventArgs is no longer required.

Answer (score 5):

What is really important here is that you can easily UPGRADE your event later to have MORE details and don't break existing decoupled listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example of how you might use your code:

```
public class MyClass () {        
    public event EventHandler<ClickedEventArgs> ClickedEvent = delegate {};  //Register the event

    protected void SomethingWasClicked(int x, int y) {    
        ClickedEvent(this, new ClickedEventArgs(x,y));   //Invoke the event that is subscribed to
    }

}

public class AnotherClass () {

    public AnotherClass () {
        MyClass mClass = new MyClass();
        mClass.ClickedEvent += new EventHandler(mClass_clickedEvent);
    }

    protected void mClass_clickedEvent(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e) {
        //Retrieve the X parameter that was passed from the MyClass instance
        int x = e.X;  
    }
}
```